# Missing required param: number error in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm definitely a newcomer to javacsript. I copied some code from another stackoverflow post to multiply the values in two input elements and put the result into a third element.

The html/javascript is:

```js
function Calculate() {
 
 var qty = document.getElementbyId("MemberQty").value;
        alert(qty);
 if (qty!='') {
  var price = document.getElementbyId("MemberPrice").value;
  var mcost = parseint(qty) * parseint(price);
  document.getElementbyId("MemberCost").value = mcost;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementbyId("MemberCost").value = '';
 }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th align="left">Type</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="text" size="3" style="text-align:right;" name="MemberQty" id="MemberQty" autocomplete="off" />
    </td>
    <td>Member tickets</td>
    <td>$
      <input type="text" size="5" value="20" name="MemberPrice" id="MemberPrice" readonly disabled style="background-color:#d9dfe5;border-style:none;" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">$
      <input type="text" size="5" name="MemberCost" id="MemberCost" readonly disabled style="background-color:#d9dfe5;border-style:none;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">
      <button onClick="Calculate()">Calculate</td>
    <td align="right">TOTAL</td>
    <td align="center">$
      <input type="text" size="5" id="TotalCharge" disabled readonly style="background-color:#d9dfe5;border-style:none;">
  </tr>
</table>
```

When Calculate() is executed, I immediately get an error "Missing required param: number".  The alert dialog doesn't show so it must be the first line of the script that causes the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: It's `parseInt` not `parseint`. Js is case sensitive.

Comment: Two things. First, you're getting an error because you cannot put `<script>` tags in the javascript section of the code snippet. Second, you have two spelling errors in your javascript. `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById` and `parseint` should be `parseInt`. Methods in javascript are always camelcased like that

Comment: If I click your Calculate button, I get the error `TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function` (this is because the b in by is lowercase). Could you show us code that actually produces the error you say it does?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections everyone.  After fixing the typos, all works fine.  I've also added the changes suggested by Sandro.

Answer (score 1):

Some flaws in your code:

turn all occurrances of

```
document.getElementbyId
```

into

```
document.getElementById
```

change

```
parseint(qty)
```

into

```
parseInt(qty,10)
```

parseInt was mispelled: this is the correct syntax for 10-base input numbers.

change

```
parseint(price)
```

into

```
parseFloat(price)
```

same as before, but you can handle prices with decimals too

change

```
<button onClick="Calculate()">
```

into

```
<button onclick="javascript:Calculate()">
```

Take care to announce the language interpreted by the given event (onclick, here).
I would also suggest to write

```
qty = parseInt(qty,10);
if ( isNaN(qty) ) qty = 0 ;
```

right after

```
var qty = document.getElementbyId("MemberQty").value;
```

At last, turn

```
if (qty!='')
```

into

```
if (qty >= 0)
```

Hope this helps and happy coding !